# What does this mean in English?

Tags: meaning

I wasn’t sure what this person meant when she said

你的国语太累

Not sure if I used the right lei?

Comment: Are you sure it is not 雷?  https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%B7_(%E7%B6%B2%E8%B7%AF%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E)

Comment: What is the context?

Answer (score 2):

你的国语太累 - This is an indirect/descriptive (informal) sentence to criticize someone's lousy speaking capability. The direct (formal) way will be "你的国语太差了".

The complete meaning in English is - Your Mandarin (speech) is so lousy, I am tired from just listening to it. And a Chinese would say "你的国语太差了, 我聽的(着)都累".

It is interesting to know how to make a compliment using the same sentence structure/style: "你的国语太牛了" :)

Comment: @Tang Ho I guess you are thinking about Cantonese. I was pointing to the official Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

你的国语太累

It is certainly a critical assessment of someone's way of speaking Mandarin. My first reaction is 累 = tiresome. However, the context suggest otherwise.

So, how about "Your Mandarin is too cumbrous"?, cumbrous being defined as "not elegant or graceful"?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, 国语 means Chinese Mandarin because it's always used by Chinese people (mostly taiwanese and Hongkongers) but it can also means "Your national language" too.

If you are a foreigner, let's say you are in China, and someone told you that "你的国语太累(了)". It may means that he/she was referring to your country's language.

For example, you are a German and you're talking to Chinese person and she says 你的国语太累了. The Chinese person may implies that German language is very tired or difficult to learn.

To clarify this. You should ask that guys, Do you mean my country's language? (你的意思是我国家的语言吗？)